# Segmentation fault using glGetString() with pthreads under linux

Tags: linux, opengl, pthreads, glut, glew

I'm trying to load textures in a background thread to help speed up my application.

The stack we are using is C/C++ on Linux, compiling with gcc. We're using OpenGL, GLUT and GLEW. We have been using libSOIL for texture loading.

Ultimately, launching texture loads with libSOIL fails because it encounters a glGetString() call that causes a segfault. Trying to narrow down the problem, I wrote a very simple OpenGL application that reproduces the behavior. The below code sample shouldn't "do anything," but it also shouldn't segfault. If I knew why it did, I could in theory rework libSOIL so that it would behave in a pthreaded environment.

```
void *glPthreadTest( void* arg ) {

  glGetString( GL_EXTENSIONS ); //SIGSEGV
  return NULL;

}

int main( int argc, char **argv ) {

  glutInit( &argc, argv );
  glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH );

  glewInit();

  glGetString( GL_EXTENSIONS ); // Does not cause SIGSEGV 

  pthread_t id;
  if (pthread_create( &id, NULL, glPthreadTest, (void*)NULL ) != 0)
    fprintf( stderr, "phtread_create glPthreadTest failed.\n" );

  glutMainLoop();
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}
```

A sample stacktrace for this application from gdb looks like this:

```
#0  0x00000038492f86e9 in glGetString () from /usr/lib64/nvidia/libGL.so.1
No symbol table info available.
#1  0x0000000000404425 in glPthreadTest (arg=0x0) at sf.cpp:168
No locals.
#2  0x0000003148e07d15 in start_thread (arg=0x7ffff7b36700) at pthread_create.c:308
        __res = <optimized out>
        pd = 0x7ffff7b36700
        now = <optimized out>
        unwind_buf = {cancel_jmp_buf = {{jmp_buf = {140737349117696, -5802871742031723458, 1, 211665686528, 140737349117696, 0, 5802854601940796478, 
                -5829171783283899330}, mask_was_saved = 0}}, priv = {pad = {0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0}, data = {prev = 0x0, cleanup = 0x0, canceltype = 0}}}
        not_first_call = 0
        pagesize_m1 = <optimized out>
        sp = <optimized out>
        freesize = <optimized out>
#3  0x00000031486f246d in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:114
No locals.
```

You'll notice I am using the nvidia libGL implementation, but this also occurs identically with the mesa libgl that Ubuntu uses for Intel HD graphics cards.

Any tips for what might be going wrong, or how to investigate further to see what's happening?

Edit: Here are the #includes and the compile string for my example test:

```
#include <SOIL.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>
#include <GL/freeglut_ext.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <cstdio>
```

`g++ -Wall -pedantic -I/usr/include/SOIL -O0 -ggdb -o sf sf.cpp -lSOIL -pthread -lGL -lGLU -lGLEW -lglut -lX11`

Comment: Can you also add what flags you are using for gcc?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In order for any OpenGL call to operate properly, it requires an *OpenGL context*.  Contexts are created using a window-system binding call (like `wglCreateContext` or similar).  After creating a context, it needs to be *"made current"*, which means associating the context with the current thread of execution.  This is accomplished with another window-system specific call (like `wglMakeCurrent` for Microsoft Windows, or `glXMakeCurrent` for X Windows).  GLUT abstracts all of that complexity away from you, doing all of those operations when you call `glutCreateWindow`.

Now, an important rule to know is that only a single OpenGL context can be current to a thread of execution at any one time.  So, in the OP's original example, if she/he could make the context current in the Pthread they created, then the context would be lost in the main thread.  The way to keep all this consistent is to only use a single context in a single thread.  (It's possible to have OpenGL contexts share data, but that's neither exposed by GLUT, nor possible without using the window-system context creation calls).

In your case, it's likely that GLUT doesn't allow access to what you really need (i.e., the OpenGL context), to make it current in the other thread.  You'd need to create and manage OpenGL contexts yourself.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. I'll see if I can't thread the actual loading of the data for the texture instead, which might give me the functionality I really wanted.

Comment: You'll certainly be able to read the texels from another file, but you won't be able to specify them as a texture (by calling `glTexImage2D` for example).  That would still need the context to be bound in the other thread, or ideally, having a context per thread with object sharing.  That said, you can totally do what you're asking, just not in GLUT. HTH.

Comment: @JohnHuston: Loading the texture from file in a separate thread is reasonable. Also you can pass it to OpenGL from there using Pixel Buffer Objects. PBOs have the ability to be mapped into client address space, spanning all threads. So you can to a glMapBuffer in the OpenGL thread and signals some event to the other thread. The loader thread fills the mapped buffer and when done signals the OpenGL thread to glUnmapBuffer..glTex[Sub]Image the data.